# Is getElementsByTagName a safe call to make accross all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just looking at other peoples .js code to learn from, and this site that uses jQuery actually makes references to:

```
document.getElementsByTagName
```

I'm guessing this is faster that using a jQuery selectory, is it safe across all browsers?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is widely supported.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t12

It is used in jQuery as well:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/core.js#L164

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/core.js#L576

Comment: This brings up an important point: jQuery uses native selectors when it can. Find out which ones it uses and you won't have to worry about a selector speed difference (not that it matters with your average site)

Comment: @Mike: Very true. jQuery has a couple optimizations it'll use if possible before it sends the request to Sizzle. Even then, Sizzle tries to use `querySelectorAll` if it is available in the browser. If not (or if qsa throws and error), then it defaults to the Sizzle engine.